# How to show URL Images in TableView cell without stuck?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsurl

I have showed collections of `URLImage` in `tableview` cell. It is stuck while I am scrolling the cell. I have used third parties like `SDWebImageManager` and `AFNetWorking`. Never the less the cell has been stuck.

```
[imageVw setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imgaeRecord.PreviewURl]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default-thumbnail.jpg"]];
```

**OR**

```
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:[self.MoviesListImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadImageWithURL:url
                      options:0
                     progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                        // progression tracking code
                     }
                    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                    if (image) {
                        cell.recipeImageView.image = image;
                    }
                }];
```

Comment: Does the title mean "stuck"?  And what do you mean by stuck, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Are you using a default cell or a custom one?

Comment: after the image download completion check if it is main thread : NSThread.isMainThread() .If not jump to main thread and update UI : dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ //cell.recipeImageView.image = image; })

Comment: @danh stuck means the table view has been stucked while am scrolling the cell.

Comment: @tx2 Here i have used custom cell (HorizontalTableViewCell). for showing the cells horizontally.

Comment: @PANKAJVERMA Sure i will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:[self.MoviesListImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadImageWithURL:url
                  options:0
                 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger  expectedSize) {
                    // progression tracking code
           }
                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                if (image) {
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   TableViewCellClass *updateCell = (id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                   if (updateCell)
                     updateCell.yourImageView.image = image;
               });
           }
       }
}];
[task resume];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use SDWebImage in this way inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:[self.MoviesListImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                 cell.recipeImageView.image = image
  }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem remains with the performance of the tableview when you have to do many image requests operations. So, in order to optimize the requests you should cancel the request that are being made when the cell leaves the visible area of the tableview. To accomplish that, in your custom cell implement `- (void)prepareForReuse` method and in there, assuming that you are using SDWebImage, do `[imageView sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad]`. Also, to download and assign the image to the `ImageView` you only need to do

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]]
```